# Run mvn clean install and mvn spring-boot:run from specific directories in command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to achieve two different src folders for a `springboot` application.

The folder structure will be

```
-simpleSpringboot
  -src
    -main
      -java
        -simpleSpringboot
          -SimpleSpringbootApplication.java
      -resources
    -test
  -solution
    -main
      -java
        -simpleSpringboot
          -SimpleSpringbootApplication.java
      -resources
    -test
  pom.xml
```

So here **Will it be possible to do the `mvn clean install` and `mvn spring-boot:run` from src folder at sometimes and from solution folder at sometimes?**

Will it be possible to pass the actual src folder path in the mvn commands?

I googled many but didn't get a proper answer.

Please guide me on this if this approach is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe use two dir, `src-q`, `src-answer`, create a link `ln -s src-q src` , or `ln -s src-answer src`, create a `q.sh` or `a.sh` to switch link.